# Immigration medical records/history

Tags: usa, immigration, medical

My sponsor company for a US work visa has asked me to obtain my medical records in preparation for a future medical examination at the US embassy.

Listed is an incident involving needing PEP after a sexual exposure. That is all that is stated on the summary online. However, I am in the process of obtaining fuller hard copy records and worried that a hard drug being taken that same night (reported to the nurse) may also come up in the paperwork. This is a one off incident.

Does the immigration doctor merely require immunisation records rather than a full history?

And what impact might this blip have?!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer about what the doctor requires, but in terms of impact, you should tread carefully and probably seek advice from a US immigration lawyer. Admitting to past use of illegal drugs can be grounds for denial of any US entry or visa [(8 USC 1182(a)(2)(A)(i)(II))](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1182), and there is no limitation on how long they can remember and consider evidence of such past events. Although doctor-patient confidentiality in the US is generally strong, such confidentiality would not apply to an immigration doctor who is certified by the US government to examine prospective immigrants.